# Comparison of values in a columns in a data frame inside a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames each containing 3 columns,

```
df.1 <- data.frame(data=cbind(rnorm(5, 0), rnorm(5, 2), rnorm(5, 5)))
df.2 <- data.frame(data=cbind(rnorm(5, 0), rnorm(5, 2), rnorm(5, 5)))

names(df.1) <- c("a", "b", "c")
names(df.2) <- c("a", "b", "c")

ls.1<- list(df.1,df.2)
names(ls.1) <- c("cat", "dog")
ls.1
```

Now I also have another list containing 3 columns.

```
df.1 <- data.frame(data=cbind(rnorm(5, 0), rnorm(5, 2), rnorm(5, 5)))
df.2 <- data.frame(data=cbind(rnorm(5, 0), rnorm(5, 2), rnorm(5, 5)))

names(df.1) <- c("a", "b", "c")
names(df.2) <- c("a", "b", "c")

ls.2<- list(df.1,df.2)
names(ls.2) <- c("cow", "pig")
ls.2
```

I want to compare **column b of cat** with **column b of cow***, and if the entire value of columns are equal say `TRUE` else `FALSE` for the column and then move on to compare
**column b of dog** with **column b of pig***. The value return will be a single `TRUE` if all the values of the compared columns are same or a single `FALSE`. If I have 5 dataframe in a list I should have 5 `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

I tried this, but it did not work.

```
chcfunc <- function(a,b){(ifelse(a[[,2]]==b[[,2]],FALSE,TRUE))}
chc <- lapply(ls.1,ls.2,chcfunc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to compare the 'b' columns in corresponding `list` elements, use `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(function(x, y) all(x$b == y$b, na.rm = TRUE), ls.1, ls.2)
```

Or use `setequal`

```
Map(setequal, ls.1, ls.2)
```

---

Or with `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(ls.1, ls.2, ~ all(.x$b == .y$b, na.rm = TRUE))
```